# Rehashing a struct hash table

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I made a rehash function but it doesnt seem to be working, and I don't know what else to do. Here is my code. I think the problem is in the loop

```
 struct hashT *hashtable; //global variable

struct hash{
 int size;
 int num_entries;
 struct Node table[];//the hash table
} *hashT;



 struct Node {
  struct Node *next;
 char* word;
 int count;
 int score;
 } *head;

 struct hastT Rehash(struct hashT *hashtable) {
     struct hastT *new_hashtable =  realloc(hashtable,2*sizeof(hashtable->table[hashtable->size]));
    struct Node *temp;
    unsigned long key;


new_hashtable->size = 2*hashtable->size;

for (int i=0; i< hashtable->size; i++){
    for (temp = hashtable->table[i]; temp; temp = temp->next;) {
        if (hashtable->table[i] != NULL) {
            key = hashF(hashtable->table[i]->word);
            new_hashtable->table[key]->word = hashtable->table[i]->word;
            new_hashtable->num_entries++;
        }
    }   
}
return (new_hashtable);

}
```

Comment: 1) you are reallocating a too small size 2) when reshuffeling you should realise that hashtable and new_hashtabel can actually be the same pointer,, they **at least** have the same contents, unless realloc() failed, which you should check.

Comment: `struct hashT` or `struct hastT`? Aren't you supposed to return a pointer to the hashtable struct from `Rehash`? And what is `temp` for if you always access `hashtable->table[i]` in the loop?

Comment: Plus: after realloc, the `table[i].next` pointers still have their old values, pointing into the old memory area (which is not valid anymore)

Comment: @wildplasser i added the realloc check, but how should the statement be?Should it be (struct hashT*) realloc(hashtable,2*sizeof(hashtable->table[hashtable->size])); ??

Comment: I suggest you add a few `printf()`s to the code to print the various `sizeof`s. They will not be what you expect them to be.